# Convergence of integral and integral of squared function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Does there exist a real continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert f(x)\lvert \ dx < \infty \tag 1 $$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert f(x)\lvert² \ dx = \infty \tag 2 $$

**EDIT**

Without the continuity assumption, this statisfies the conditions:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ in $0<x<1$; $f(x)=0$ otherwise

Comment: It might improve your Question to include more context:  What examples did you consider and discard?  Why is this an interesting exercise?  Not everything needs to be included, but it helps Readers to provide an Answer that will help you learn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: define $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ if $0<x<1$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, forgot a key part: f continuous

Comment: Ok, try to construct $f$ so that it has a sequence of  rectangular "bumps" of length $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and height $n$ (adjusted so that $f$ is continuous, of course).